# Python's str() function not actually a function?

Tags: python

I was under the impression that something like `str(5)` is calling the `str` function on the integer `5`. But when you type `str` into the interpreter:

```
>>> str
<class 'str'>
```

So `str` is actually a class, which makes code like `if type(a) is str` make more sense. But then why is `str` listed under "Built-in Functions" in the docs? Is this just a simplification?

Comment: `str` is the name of the ctor for the `str` class, essentially.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Listing it as a function is a bit of a simplification, yes. But remember that classes are callable* — that's how you create an instance of a class!

If it helps you any, think of `str(5)` as **constructing** a string from the number `5`.

Note that all of the other built-in types exist the same way: `int()`, `float()`, `str()`, `tuple()`, `list()`, `set()`, `file()`... they're all classes, but they can be called to construct an instance of their class, and will usually accept an instance of another type as an argument if it's applicable.

*: At least, most of the time.

Comment: Which class is not callable?

Comment: [An abstract class.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13646245/149341) Since you can't have an instance of the abstract class itself, it's not callable. (Well, you can call it, but it will always raise an exception.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So still, you can safely say that every class is callable, or at least - every class has a `__call__` method.

Comment: Yes. All classes are callable; some just don't do anything useful when you call them.

Answer (score 1):

`str(5)` is actually calling the `__call__()` function on the str class:

```
>>> str(5)
'5'
>>> str.__call__(5)
'5'
```

So yes, str is behaving as a function as well as a class (or a type in versions prior to 2.7)

Comment: Note that this is how **all** function calls work. Every function has a `__call__` method on it. (Including the `__call__` function itself; it's turtles all the way down!)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way to look at it is that str() returns an instance of the str class.