# Python abstract class shall force derived classes to initialize variable in __init__

Tags: python, oop, abstract-class

I want to have an abstract class which forces every derived class to set certain attributes in its `__init__` method.

I've looked at several questions which did not fully solve my problem, specifically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800659/python-abstract-class-init) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736255/abstract-attributes-in-python). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960337/how-to-create-abstract-properties-in-python-abstract-classes) looked promising but I couldn't manage to get it working.

I assume my desired outcome could look like the following **pseudo code**:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class Quadrature(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @someMagicKeyword            #<==== This is what I want, but can't get working
    xyz

    @someMagicKeyword            #<==== This is what I want, but can't get working
    weights


    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, order):
        pass


    def someStupidFunctionDefinedHere(self, n):
        return self.xyz+self.weights+n



class QuadratureWhichWorks(Quadrature):
    # This shall work because we initialize xyz and weights in __init__
    def __init__(self,order):
        self.xyz = 123
        self.weights = 456

class QuadratureWhichShallNotWork(Quadrature):
    # Does not initialize self.weights
    def __init__(self,order):
        self.xyz = 123
```

Here are some of the things I have tried:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class Quadrature(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def xyz(self):
        pass


    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def weights(self):
        pass


    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, order):
        pass


    def someStupidFunctionDefinedHere(self, n):
        return self.xyz+self.weights+n



class QuadratureWhichWorks(Quadrature):
    # This shall work because we initialize xyz and weights in __init__
    def __init__(self,order):
        self.xyz = 123
        self.weights = 456
```

Then I try to create an instance:

```
>>> from example1 import * 
>>> Q = QuadratureWhichWorks(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class QuadratureWhichWorks with abstract methods weights, xyz
>>>
```

Which tells me to implement the methods, but I thought I said that these are `properties`?

My current work-around has the flaw, that the `__init__` method can be overwritten in the derived classes but for now this at least ensures (to me) that I always know that the requested properties are set:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class Quadrature(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def computexyz(self,order):
        pass


    @abstractmethod
    def computeweights(self,order):
        pass


    def __init__(self, order):
        self.xyz = self.computexyz(order)
        self.weights = self.computeweights(order)

    def someStupidFunctionDefinedHere(self, n):
        return self.xyz+self.weights+n



class QuadratureWhichWorks(Quadrature):

    def computexyz(self,order):
        return order*123

    def computeweights(self,order):
        return order*456


class HereComesTheProblem(Quadrature):

    def __init__(self,order):
        self.xyz = 123
        # but nothing is done with weights

    def computexyz(self,order):
        return order*123

    def computeweights(self,order): # will not be used
        return order*456
```

But the problem is

```
>>> from example2 import * 
>>> Q = HereComesTheProblem(10)
>>> Q.xyz
123
>>> Q.weights
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'HereComesTheProblem' object has no attribute 'weights'
```

How is this implemented correctly?

Comment: One option is to have the subclasses call the superclass's `__init__` function. See this question on how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399307/how-to-invoke-the-super-constructor

Comment: In case of `HereComesTheProblem`, do you want `weights` attr to be initializes to `None`, or do you want the while creating instance of `HereComesTheProblem`, the error should be thrown that "weight is not provided"?

Comment: @pnv I want an error message when trying to create an instance of `HereComesTheProblem`.

Comment: @k1next can you take a look at the solution I gave down below and give some feedback

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### **Edit:** Solution with a custom metaclass.

It's worth noting that custom metaclasses are often frowned upon, but you can solve this problem with one.
[Here](https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/) is a good write up discussing how they work and when they're useful. The solution here is essentially to tack on a check for the attribute that you want after the `__init__` is invoked.

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

# our version of ABCMeta with required attributes
class MyMeta(ABCMeta):
    required_attributes = []

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(MyMeta, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        for attr_name in obj.required_attributes:
            if not getattr(obj, attr_name):
                raise ValueError('required attribute (%s) not set' % attr_name)
        return obj

# similar to the above example, but inheriting MyMeta now
class Quadrature(object, metaclass=MyMeta):
    required_attributes = ['xyz', 'weights']

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, order):
        pass


class QuadratureWhichWorks(Quadrature):
    # This shall work because we initialize xyz and weights in __init__
    def __init__(self,order):
        self.xyz = 123
        self.weights = 456

q = QuadratureWhichWorks('foo')

class QuadratureWhichShallNotWork(Quadrature):
    def __init__(self, order):
        self.xyz = 123

q2 = QuadratureWhichShallNotWork('bar')
```

Below is my original answer which explores the topic more in general.

### Original Answer

I think some of this comes from confusing *instance attributes* with the objects wrapped by the `property` decorator.

- An instance attribute is a plain chunk of data nested in the namespace of the instance. Likewise, a class attribute is nested in the namespace of the class (and shared by the instances of that class unless they overwrite it).
- A property is a function with syntactic shortcuts to make them accessible as if they were attributes, but their functional nature allows them to be dynamic.

A small example without introducing abstract classes would be

```py
>>> class Joker(object):
>>>     # a class attribute
>>>     setup = 'Wenn ist das Nunstück git und Slotermeyer?'
>>> 
>>>     # a read-only property
>>>     @property
>>>     def warning(self):
>>>         return 'Joke Warfare is explicitly banned bythe Geneva Conventions'
>>> 
>>>     def __init__(self):
>>>         self.punchline = 'Ja! Beiherhund das Oder die Flipperwaldt gersput!'

>>> j = Joker()

>>> # we can access the class attribute via class or instance
>>> Joker.setup == j.setup

>>> # we can get the property but cannot set it
>>> j.warning
'Joke Warfare is explicitly banned bythe Geneva Conventions'
>>> j.warning = 'Totally safe joke...'
AttributeError: cant set attribute

>>> # instance attribute set in __init__ is only accessible to that instance
>>> j.punchline != Joker.punchline
AttributeError: type object 'Joker' has no attribute 'punchline'
```

According to the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty), since 3.3 the `abstractproperty` is redundant and actually reflects your attempted solution.
The issue with that solution is that your subclasses do not implement a concrete property, they just overwrite it with an instance attribute.
In order to continue using the `abc` package, you could handle this by implementing those properties, i.e.

```py
>>> from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
>>> class Quadrature(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):
>>> 
>>>     @property
>>>     @abstractmethod
>>>     def xyz(self):
>>>         pass
>>> 
>>>     @property
>>>     @abstractmethod
>>>     def weights(self):
>>>         pass
>>> 
>>>     @abstractmethod
>>>     def __init__(self, order):
>>>         pass
>>> 
>>>     def someStupidFunctionDefinedHere(self, n):
>>>         return self.xyz+self.weights+n
>>> 
>>> 
>>> class QuadratureWhichWorks(Quadrature):
>>>     # This shall work because we initialize xyz and weights in __init__
>>>     def __init__(self,order):
>>>         self._xyz = 123
>>>         self._weights = 456
>>> 
>>>     @property
>>>     def xyz(self):
>>>         return self._xyz
>>> 
>>>     @property
>>>     def weights(self):
>>>         return self._weights
>>> 
>>> q = QuadratureWhichWorks('foo')
>>> q.xyz
123
>>> q.weights
456
```

I think this is a bit clunky though, but it really depends on how you intend to implment subclasses of `Quadrature`.
My suggestion would be to not make `xyz` or `weights` abstract, but instead handle whether they were set at runtime, i.e. catch any `AttributeError`s that may pop up when accessing the value.

Comment: Nice solution! You miss a `*` in front of `args` in the call to super's `__call__` though.

Answer (score 3):

## Class Annotations Solution

This is possible because of changes to python 3.7 (which I hope you are using - because this is cool!) as it adds [`type hinting`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) and the ability to add class [annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), which were added for [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html). It is as close to your original desired syntax as I can think up. The superclass you will want would look something like this:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import List

class PropertyEnfocedABC(ABC):

    def __init__(self):
        annotations = self.__class__.__dict__.get('__annotations__', {})
        for name, type_ in annotations.items():
            if not hasattr(self, name):
                raise AttributeError(f'required attribute {name} not present '
                                     f'in {self.__class__}')
```

Now, to see it in action.

```
class Quadratic(PropertyEnfocedABC):

    xyz: int 
    weights: List[int] 

    def __init__(self):
        self.xyz = 2
        self.weights = [4]
        super().__init__()
```

or more accurately in your case, with a mix of abstract methods and attributes:

```
class Quadrature(PropertyEnforcedABC):

    xyz: int
    weights: int


    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, order):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def some_stupid_function(self, n):
        return self.xyz + self.weights + n
```

Now, any subclass of a subclass of a `PropertyEnforcedABC` must set the attributes that are annotated in the class (if you do not provide a type to the annotation it will not be considered an annotation) and thus if the constructor of quadratic did not set `xyz` or `weights`, an attribute error would be raised. Note you must call the constructor at the end of init, but this should not be a real problem and you can solve this by wrapping your own metaclass around the above code if you *really* don't like it.

You could modify `PropertyEnforcedABC` however you want (like enforcing the type of the properties) and more. You could even check for `Optional` and ignore those.

Comment: cool, but not using ABC

Answer (score 2):

In order to force a subclass to implement a property or method, you need to raise an error, if this method is not implemented:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod, abstractproperty

class Quadrature(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractproperty
    def xyz(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Deprecated since 3.3 : https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty