# Using Protocol-Oriented Programming (POP) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently came across a very interesting talk by James Powell on YouTube ([LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lmCu8wz8ro), around 12 minutes into the video). In his PyData talk, he states that "[...] The Python data model is a means by which you can implement protocols [...]". He relates his statement to the use of dunder-methods (like `__init__`, `__repr__`, etc.).

I've been programming for quite a while with Python, but I haven't come across POP. The video didn't really define what it is. What is POP in Python actually and how is it used in practice?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(object-oriented_programming)). Note how Python isn't mentioned there. Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731376/how-to-achieve-protocol-oriented-programming-in-python). POP isn't available in Python.

Comment: @Nearoo: I also found that site, but I thought it could possibly be outdated. I just wanted to make sure that I'm not missing a new feature or something.

Comment: Actaully, now I see what you're looking for. POP generally refers to the usage of the interface concept. An interface is like a class that only declares method signatures and defines what the implementation of these methods should do ([here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Comparable.java.html)'s an example of Java's widely used comparable interface). In a way, you can look at methods like `__repr__`, `__cmp__` etc. as interface implementations. Any object that has `__cmp__` can be compared - in Java, you'd make the object implement the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: But unlike in Java, you can't define new interfaces in Python.

Comment: Since you don't define variable types in Python, the concept of interfaces doesn't have any benefit anyway. In Python, if you write a method that requires an Object that implements a method with a certain signature, you simply note that in the documentation of that method and rely on the client to follow that.

Answer (score 3):

By python being protocol oriented, he may mean the combination of the following:

1. [Duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing): *"If it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck"*. In contrast to languages like C or C++, you don't care so much about the type of an object you are passing around but rather the interface the object provides. I see the object interface as equivalent to the sum of its methods or the *protocol* the object provides. Although typing is now part of python since [version 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) through type hints, duck typing is so deeply ingrained into the language that [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) – fittingly called "*Protocols*: Structural subtyping (static duck typing)" – embeds that very concept into the language while using static typing.
2. Methods (== protocol) are pythons means of meeting its *operators*, standard functions and even its *syntax*:

   - To use an operator like `a + b` you implement the `__add__(self, other)` method for `a`
   - To meet the requirements of a `Sized` type thus providing the standard `len(…)` function, you implement the `__len__` method
   - To use object `a` in a for loop like `for _ in a:`, you implement its `__iter__` method
   - To use object an object in a generator expression, you implement also its `__next__` method
   - To enable the *syntax* for usage in a context `with A(…) as a:` you provide `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods

   We as programmers serve python's standard means of inclusion by providing the [corresponding protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) for an object.
3. In python, *everything is an object*, strings, lists, functions and even modules. The paradigms shown above are applicable there, too. You can in principle add functions, which are first class objects. Functions itself have methods, which are objects, so they have methods, which are objects, ….

Additional note: I found your question after watching the same talk and stumbling over the same phrase. My impression is he didn't meant the term “protocol-oriented” literally but more colloquially. I think the three items above justify his phrase.

Answer (score -3):

Are you sure about pop
I think you mean oop
Object  oriented programming
Like this:

```
Class animal:
     def __init__(self, name, color):
          self.name = name
          self.color = color

Dog = animal(" huskey",  "black")
print(animal.name)
print(animal.color)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I really mean Protocol-Oriented Programming. That confused me at first, too.