# python mark a class method that must be overwritten at init

Tags: python, python-3.x

have a python3 class method that must be overwritten at init.

is there a nice way to identify this method?

as the mybool is only give at run time standard inherits want work as i don't know which base class to inherit from before the init i and so i cant use @abstractmethod

```
class Foo():
   def __init__(mybool: bool):
      if mybool:
         c = _a
      else:
         c = _b

   def _a():
     #do one
     pass
   def _b():
     #do two
     pass

   def c():
     #this will never be used
     pass
```

Comment: Looks like an XY-problem. Why not put a simple `if-else` into `c`?

Comment: See:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646245/is-it-possible-to-make-abstract-classes-in-python

Comment: I don’t need to ask if/else question every time “c” is called if I have the answer one time at init