# Meaning of "mixin methods" in Python docs

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class

The [python docs on collections.abc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.abc.html) has a nice summary table (picture below) with a column named "Mixin Methods." I'm confused by the difference between this column and the previous one.

Is it that "abstract methods" can be custom-made but "mixin methods" have a specific implementation that is fixed in all classes of a given type? If so, where can I find what's in these mixin methods?

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read here about mixins in python: https://www.residentmar.io/2019/07/07/python-mixins.html#:~:text=Mixins%20are%20an%20alternative%20class,this%20feature%E2%80%94and%20nothing%20else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An **abstract** method is one that you're supposed to implement yourself, if you inherit from any of these classes. For example:

```
class MyIter(collections.abc.Iterator):

    # We must override __next__ because it's abstract in `Iterator`.
    def __next__(self):
        ...
```

A **mixin** is a method whose *implementation* is already provided in the superclass. So you don't need to override `__iter__`, because `Iterator` already implements it.

To continue with the `Iterator` example: the `Iterator` class itself is implemented [like this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/069e81ab3da46c441335ca762c4333b7bd91861d/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L271) (slightly simplified):

```
class Iterator(Iterable):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __next__(self):
        pass

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

We're using [`abc.abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) to indicate that `__next__` is abstract; if you forget to override it in your concrete implementation class, the decorator will [cause an exception to be raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646245/is-it-possible-to-make-abstract-classes-in-python).

The `__iter__` method, on the other hand, has an implementation that simply returns `self`, as [expected from iterator objects](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__).

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer!