# Does collections.abc.Collection have a uniqueness property, like Set?

Tags: python, data-structures, set, python-typing

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes, it's clear to me that a `collections.abc.Set` is a `collections.abc.Collection`. And a useful property of `Set` is the uniqueness property (that it doesn't contain duplicated elements).

However, what I am trying to figure out is, does `Collection` have a uniqueness property?

In other words, is it possible for a `Collection` to have duplicate values inside?

Comment: A sequence (i.e. list, tuple, …) is also a collection, so "no, it has no uniqueness guarantee".

Comment: I don't think anything from `collections.abc` has any property (as you've described) at all, because they don't have any implementation. Anything can fulfil a `collections.abc.Set` as long as it has implemented concrete methods for the class and its ancestors, as listed in the `Abstract Methods` column. To make something have unique elements, you have to **implement** it as such upon container initialisation and mutation. You can easily make a subclass of `Set` which doesn't have unique elements, and force another kind of collection to only have unique elements.

Comment: These classes are what might be called "interfaces" in other languages.

Comment: @dROOOze though the docs do say "ABCs for read-only and mutable sets.", so I'd expect uniqueness. Does a set without unique elements make sense?

Comment: @dROOOze more generally, interfaces are not only defined by their types

Comment: No. And `collections.abc.Set` has no uniqueness property, AFAIK

Comment: @joel sure, they are called multisets. And a multiset could definitely satisfy `collections.abc.Set`

Comment: A uniqueness constraint is a *semantic* of the interface. ABCs only constrain the actual interface: i.e. what named methods need to exist.

Comment: Everyone forgot that `collections.abc.Set` has [mixin methods with already defined functionality.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga [See the docs here…](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#examples-and-recipes) **Several of the ABCs are also useful as mixins that make it easier to develop classes supporting container APIs. For example, to write a class supporting the full Set API, it is only necessary to supply the three underlying abstract methods: __contains__(), __iter__(), and __len__(). The ABC supplies the remaining methods such as __and__() and isdisjoint()**

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon I never stated otherwise?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga *No. And collections.abc.Set has no uniqueness property, AFAIK*. Maybe I miss understood this ‍♂️. Or maybe I didn’t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, what I am trying to figure out is, does Collection have a uniqueness property?

No it doesn’t. [All it declares are `__contains__`, `__iter__`, and `__len__`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Collection) 
Actually `collections.abc.Set` inherits from `collections.abc.Collection` then adds other features as [Mixin Methods.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set)

[See mixin method here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67369865)