# Using isinstance() versus duck typing

Tags: python, matplotlib, duck-typing, isinstance

I'm writing an interface to `matplotlib`, which requires that lists of floats are treated as corresponding to a colour map, but other types of input are treated as specifying a particular colour.

To do this, I planned to use `matplotlib.colors.colorConverter`, which is an instance of a class that converts the other types of input to `matplotlib` RGBA colour tuples. However, it will also convert floats to a grayscale colour map. This conflicts with the existing functionality of the package I'm working on and I think that would be undesirable.

My question is: is it appropriate/Pythonic to use an `isinstance()` check prior to using `colorConverter` to make sure that I don't incorrectly handle lists of floats? Is there a better way that I haven't thought of?

I've read that I should generally code to an interface, but in this case, the interface has functionality that differs from what is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little subjective, but I'd say: in general it's a not a good idea, but here where you're distinguishing between a *container* and an *instance* of a class it **is** appropriate (especially when, say, those classes may themselves be iterable, like tuples or strings and doing it the duck-typing would get quite tricky).

*Aside*: coding to an interface *is* generally recommended, but it's far more applicable to the Java-style static languages than Python, where interfaces don't really exist, unless you count abstract base classes and the `abc` module etc. (much deeper discussion in [What's the Python version for “Code against an interface, not an object”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549018/whats-the-python-version-for-code-against-an-interface-not-an-object))

Hard to say without more details, but it sounds like you're closer to building a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) here than anything, and as such you should be free to use your own (neater / tighter / different) API, insulating users from your underlying implementation (Matplotlib).

Comment: On the last bit, the issue is that I'm contributing to `networkx` and I haven't really contributed to a properly maintained package before. I am trying to keep my edits as minimal as possible, whilst adding the necessary functionality safely.

Comment: OK.. in which case, I'd go for the type-checking, or just expose an alternative / additional method on your class, if that's an option (as also suggested by the other poster).

Either way: unit tests... :)

Comment: Yup, first thing I did after forking the project was finding out how `nose` worked. It's what they use for unit testing.

Answer (score 2):

Why not write two separate functions, one that treats its input as a color map, and another that treats its input as a color?  This would be the simplest way to deal with the problem, and would both avoid surprises, and leave you room to expand functionality in the future.