# Coding against an Interface in a separate application

Tags: c#

I have written a class library with a class and an interface for the class.

At the moment the class is private and the interface is public.

If I import the dll for the class library into a console app I know that I will need to instantiate the interface like this:

```
IInterface iinterface = new Class();
```

But for that to work the Class will have to be publicly accessible too. I understand why you would want to code against the interface rather than the class but should I be giving a third party access to the class as well as the interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interface actually provides a contract, for third party library, you expect the user to **code against your interface** not to use your class. If you want the third party user to have access to your class then you should make it public.

Comment: So what syntax would you write to code against the interface without creating it as a new instance of class? This is what's confusing me.

Comment: If you are exposing your interface from the library then the user of your library would implement that interface in his/her class. Here is a very good discussion about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456424/what-do-programmers-mean-when-they-say-code-against-an-interface-not-an-objec

Comment: @markp3rry, you are welcome, you may as well see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface