# ArrayAdapter.clear kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to learn kotlin and I want to convert one of my android projects from java to kotlin. But I have a problem

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<CitySearch>>?, response: Response<List<CitySearch>>?) {
    if(response != null && response.isSuccessful) {
        val list = response.body()
        cityAdapter.clear()
        if(list != null && !list.isEmpty()){
            cityAdapter.addAll(list)
            listView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
            cityName.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error Operation is not supported for read-only collection                                                                           at kotlin.collections.EmptyList.clear() on the line with cityAdapter.clear()
I don't know how to solve it.

For all the project please check

[Problematic historic version of WeatherFragment](https://github.com/benidobre/TestKotlin/blob/61d8dc180e10a819e9b09a1555a661c462f684cc/app/src/main/java/com/example/bdobre/testkotlin/WeatherFragment.kt)

[Current Version](https://github.com/benidobre/TestKotlin/blob/feature/weather/app/src/main/java/com/example/bdobre/testkotlin/WeatherFragment.kt)

Comment: Which `kotlin` version are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At this line
 `cityAdapter = CitySearchAdapter(context, emptyList())`

[`emptyList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/empty-list.html) will gives you an immutable list (read only) so you need to use

```
cityAdapter = CitySearchAdapter(context, arrayListOf())
```

or

```
cityAdapter = CitySearchAdapter(context, mutableListOf<YourType>())
```

[Mutable Collections in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html)

[How do I initialize Kotlin's MutableList to empty MutableList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278869/how-do-i-initialize-kotlins-mutablelist-to-empty-mutablelist)

Comment: thank you man. this came into my mind this morning and I have used ArrayList<CitySearch>()

Answer (score 2):

you can initialize the arrylist globally same as follows

```
var mArrayBindStages: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
```

add data into array list define the adapter and set to adapter

```
var adapterSearch = User_Adapter_Search_Box(activity, dataList)
                val mLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 1)
                rc_RecyclerView!!.layoutManager = mLayoutManager as RecyclerView.LayoutManager?
                rc_RecyclerView!!.adapter = adapterSearch

                adapterSearch!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
```