# Difference between MutableList and List in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

1. What is the difference between **MutableList** and **List** in Kotlin?
2. and what is the **use** of each type?

Comment: You may take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727657/kotlin-and-immutable-collections).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin and Immutable Collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727657/kotlin-and-immutable-collections)

Answer (score 73):

From docs:

[List](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html): A generic ordered collection of elements. Methods in this interface support only read-only access to the list; read/write access is supported through the MutableList interface.

[MutableList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html): A generic ordered collection of elements that supports adding and removing elements.

You can modify a MutableList: change, remove, add... its elements. In a List you can only read them.

Answer (score 27):

> SUMMARY: List is read-only while MutableList allows you to add, edit and remove items

- **List**

  ```
   var language: List<String> = listOf("java", "kotlin", "dart")
  ```

List type is an interface which provides read-only access. you are limited to read operations like

> get, indexof, subList, contains, size etc

with kotlin you have access to some more functions **like sort, stream,binarySearch

- **MutableList**

Consider this example:

```
    var mutableLanguage: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("java", "kotlin", "dart")
```

with mutablelist you can perform read and write operation i.e., add or remove contents of a list. beside supporting all the functions of interface type List.

> add, addAll, replace, replaceAll, set, removeAt etc