# How does add method works for List<E> type val in kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I'm having a variable like

```
val itemList:List<String> = ArrayList()
itemList.add("One")
itemList.add("Two")
```

How can i achieve this in kotlin

Comment: Yes but the add method is not working here, it's giving compile time error

Comment: listOf("One", "Two") gives you initialized List right away

Comment: Yes but in that case i won't be able to add elements runtime

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi check my answer.

Comment: If you want to go Kotlin way, it's better to use higher order interface, in your case that would be MutableList<T>, it has ability to modify the list, if you need immutable list use List<T>. so your line would be *val list: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()*

Comment: @ViktorYakunin Thanks

Comment: why not use `val itemList: List<String> = listOf("One", "Two")`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Don't**

```
val itemList:List<String> = ArrayList()
```

**Do**

```
 val itemList:MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
```

You should use [**`MutableList`**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html).

```
interface MutableList<E> : List<E>, MutableCollection<E> (source)
```

A generic ordered collection of elements that supports adding and removing elements.

**DEMO**

```
 val itemList:MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    itemList.add("One")
    itemList.add("Two")
```

Comment: Your solution works. Cudos for that. but in that case i'm not able to keep the type of a variable to List

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi, you should not keep the type to `List`, it should be `MutableList` in Kotlin since `List` is a read-only interface which does not expose mutating functions. See [another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445909) and [the language reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html).

Comment: Provide me a solution where i can keep the type of variable to List I'll accept your answer

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi there is no way to "keep the type of variable to List" and add elements.

Comment: imho **Do** should really be `val itemList = mutableListOf<String>()`

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

```
val itemList: List<String> = arrayListOf<String>().apply {
    add("One")
    add("Two")
}
// no need for .add method anymore!
```

Another option:

```
val itemList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
// or
val itemList = mutableListOf<String>()

// now you have `.add()` function
```

You should generally prefer non-modifiable lists instead of modifiable lists. For example, in Java, you could only use `Collections.unmodifiableList` and get a runtime exception if you tried to make a modification. With Kotlin, you can make it into a compile-time validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
class UserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
val itemList= ArrayList<String>()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    itemList.add("One")
    itemList.add("Two")
}
```

}