# Which function to use for making a copy of a list in kotlin

Tags: list, filter, kotlin

Having a list of Data

```
val list: List<Data>
```

And want to make a shallow copy of it into a new list.

There are a few ways could do it in kotlin,  wondering which one should be used in which case?

`list?.filter` is similar to  `mutableListOf`,  but `listOf` seems different.

Anyone suggestion?

```
val copyData = list?.filter{true}

copyData = mutableListOf(list)

copyData = listOf(list)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter two options, `mutableListOf(list)` and `listOf(list)`, don't actually copy a list, they only create a new list which has a single item pointing to the `list`. This is not a shallow copy of `list`, because you cannot observe its older content as it changes.

The `list.filter { true }` option works, i.e. you get a new list that is a copy of `list`, but it is not an idiomatic solution as it might hurt readability of the code.

Instead, consider [`list.toList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-list.html) and [`list.toMutableList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-list.html), based on the desired mutability.

Comment: thx @hotkey! the list.toList() seems is same as toMutibleList()?    

list.toMutableList() ==>

    public fun <T> Collection<T>.toMutableList(): MutableList<T> {
        return ArrayList(this)
    }

;   and list.toList() ==>
     
    inline fun <T> java.util.Enumeration<T>.toList(): List<T> = java.util.Collections.list(this)
;  which call into  
    public static <T> ArrayList<T> list(Enumeration<T> e) {
        ArrayList<T> l = new ArrayList<>();
        while (e.hasMoreElements())
            l.add(e.nextElement());
        return l;
    }

Comment: They are similar, though the list they return is exposed as an instance of different interfaces: the Kotlin `List<T>`, unlike Java, is an interface for read-only lists, and `MutableList<T>` has mutating functions. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445909/difference-between-mutablelist-and-list-in-kotlin, and the docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [`filter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) if you really want to filter the incoming list and work with the filtered one instead. Using `filter{true}` doesn't really make sense.

Use [`toMutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-list.html) if you need to adapt the returned list, e.g. you need to add additional elements or remove some.

Finally, use [`toList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-list.html) if you require a new list containing the same elements, which doesn't allow adding/removing elements. You may also want to check the Kotlin reference regarding [Collections: List, Set, Map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html)

The ones you mentioned, i.e. `mutableListOf` and `listOf` are just convenience methods to create new lists containing whatever you passed.. so you actually constructed a list of lists.

Comment: thx @Roland!.  filter{true} could be useful in the case the copy does not want be affected by the source's change. i.e.   when giving the list snapshot to listView's adapter, it may not want to be affected by the original source list's change later.

Comment: `filter { true }` is basically just the same as calling `toList()` ;-) I really recommend you the last link I added regarding the collections. Most of the methods return immutable collections, except you call something like `mutableListOf`, `mutableMap`, etc.